# Understanding catching checked exceptions

Tags: java, exception, checked-exceptions

I'm reading J. Bloch's Effective Java and now I'm at the section about checked/unchecked exceptions. He said that (emphasize mine):

> By confronting the API user with a checked exception, the API designer
>   pre- sents a mandate to recover from the condition. The user can
>   disregard the mandate by catching the exception and ignoring it, but
>   this is usually a ***bad idea***(Item 65).

Now, consider a method returning a list of all static data members of a class having the same type or a subtype:

```
public static <T> List<? extends T> getPublicStaticFields(Class<T> clazz){
    List<T> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Field f : clazz.getDeclaredFields()){
        if(Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers()) && 
                 Modifier.isPublic(f.getModifiers())){
            Object fieldValue;
            try {
                fieldValue = f.get(null);
                if(clazz.isAssignableFrom(fieldValue.getClass()))
                    fields.add((T) fieldValue);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) { } // <------- Ignoring the execption
        }
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(fields);
}
```

The thing is I have no idea what I should put in the exception handler. I perform the access checking in the if condition:

```
f(Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers()) && 
    Modifier.isPublic(f.getModifiers()))
```

therefore `IllegalAccessViolation` will never be thrown. Moreover it seems a little confused why `IllegalAccessViolation` is checked. I think it's a programming error, and judjing by what he said:

> **use checked exceptions for conditions from which the caller can**
>   **reasonably be expected to recover**
>
> [...]
>
> **Use runtime exceptions to**
>   **indicate programming errors**

I though it should be an uncheked one.

***QUESTION:*** Is it considered appropriate to leave a hadler of a checked exception empty if we ensured that the expcetion will never be thrown somewhere before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of ignoring the exception, add

```
throw new AssertionError("this should never happen");
```

to the catch block. That way, if you misunderstood the documentation and this `IllegalAccessException` exception effectively happens, or if someone modifies the code and removes the checks that make this `IllegalAccessException` exception impossible, you'll have a clear exception, with a stack trace indicating the precise location where the problem is, rather than a problem later, in unrelated code, or worse: a valid but incorrect result.